# opensource java framework for P2P

Tags: java, p2p

I want to distribute the files in network in quick time.Consider that my network has 100 PC.
1 PC will act as server.Server will hold all files.Now if server wants to send file to certain number of pcs in network then it should happen in quick time.

So i am using following strategy :

1. Server sends  command all intended pcs to get files from their nearest location.
2. Initially Server sends file to 2 pcs.pc1 and pc2
3. Now all other pcs will pick the file from the nearest availabe pcs.(server, pc1 and pc2)
4. This continues

Which java framework is best for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [JXTA project](https://jxta.dev.java.net/).

Comment: thanks:Is it the best?The files that will be transfered using this softwares will be large in size

Comment: @ako Release 2.7 (see http://jxse.kenai.com) is the most recent and most tested available. You can transfer large size files with Bibdrectional pipes.

Answer (score 0):

The [AntHill Project](http://www.cs.unibo.it/projects/anthill/) also seems like a good place to start.